Action movie with double entendres in the dialog
I remember watching an action movie, perhaps in the 1990's or earlier, where the hero would come out with these hilariously funny double entendres.  One that I can vaguely remember...
The girl asks the hero, "What happened to ---so and so---?"
And the hero answers,  "He had to split."
"Split" is slang for leaving.  So he was saying 'he left'. But as a double entendre, the hero had just essentially sliced the guy in half (i.e., 'split'). And these lines were delivered deadpan casual. Clever!
What might this be?  I would be grateful for the IMDB or Amazon link so I could order the video.

Reminds me of a similar gag in The Running Man, but this is pretty vague at the moment, to be honest. It's quite possible that there was more than one film that used that line. And a huge amount of these films have heroes deadpanning puns.

http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BondOneLiner

That exact line is in The Running Man.




The Schwartzenegger Staple.  That was used a lot in Total Recall as well.  "Hey Benny!  SCREW YOUUUUUUUUUUUU!!!!"
